# JS Power of Issue

Tags: javascript, math

I have been given a calculation in Excel, that I have to replicate in JS, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

The calculation in Excel is `70*3^0.75`. The result is `159.565493987`, rounded to 160.

In JS I have tried the following

```
Math.pow(70 * 3, .75); // 55.16510778290732
Math.pow(70, .75) * 3; // 72.60136477480762
70*.75*3;              // 157.5
```

Comment: What about `70 * Math.pow(3, .75)` ? :)

Comment: I had the numbers the wrong way around didn't I. Dammit. Thanks buddy.

Comment: :-) Voting to close as typo.

Comment: I'm okay with that. I'll do the same. It's been a long day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
console.log(70 * Math.pow(3, .75))
// or just
console.log(70 * 3 ** .75)
```

In JavaScript, like most languages, exponentiation evaluates before multiplication. See [order of operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table).

**Note:** The exponentiation operator `**` was added in the [ECMAScript 2016 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-exp-operator), so if you want to use it portably, consider a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) for your script.